# How can I show Marker on Google Maps in URL?

Tags: google-maps, iframe

Here I'm using an iFrame and passing one URL with dynamic latitude/longitude:

```
<iframe width="270" height="250" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.co.in/maps?f=d&source=s_d&t=k&layer=t&hl=en&mra=ls&ie=UTF8&geocode=&hq=&sll=<?php echo $latitude;?>,<?php $longitude;?>&spn=0.0183632,0.0215679&z=15&output=embed"></iframe>
```

Can I set a marker on the particular location I pass in as parameters?

Answer (score 5):

Easily! Just put your arguments in:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=description+(name)+%4046.080271,6.465248
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace http://maps.google.co.in with http://ditu.google.cn

Don't know why, but it works for me.